# What is the point of reassigning argument variables?

Tags: javascript

I realise that it is useful (for performance reasons) to do something like...

```
function Abc(a, b, c) {
    var window = window;
```

So when the code accesses `window`, it doesn't need to go up the scope chain to finally find `window`. The same can be done for `document`, `navigator`, etc...

But I'm in the process of rewriting some of the [MobiScroll jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/) and found this...

```
function Scroller(elm, dw, settings) {
    ...
    var elm = elm;
    var dw = dw;
    ...
```

What are the advantages of reinitialising `elm` and `dw` to point to their argument variables ?

I've read a lot about accessing `arguments` being costly, but never read anything about why this might be good practice.

What are the benefits in doing this?

<sup>In the past, I've [deliberately removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload&action=history) this construct from MDN documentation.</sup>

Comment: Never seen it. Let the engine worry about the "optimizations".

Comment: @pst I agree. However, I have a curious mind...

Comment: It's more or less a duplicate of [Javascript - Do I need to use 'var' when reassigning a variable defined in the function's parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495174/javascript-do-i-need-to-use-var-when-reassigning-a-variable-defined-in-the-fu). However, I don't know whether these are the answers you want.

Comment: @Felix That question is more of *should I?* whilst mine is *what is the point?*. Hopefully there is a difference :) Maybe the answer  to my question is *They are doing it wrong*. Reading more of the source, there are questionable things (such as `Array()` for new `Array`s, `for ( in )` without `hasOwnProperty()` safety, etc).

Comment: Yes, maybe that was the difference I "felt" ;)

Comment: I think local variables are checked before arguments

Comment: @gladosccc Sounds like a *pull out the specific part of ECMA spec to answer* type question :)

Comment: From a code look point of view its confusing. 
From a performance point of view, lets see http://jsperf.com/reassigning-argument-variables

Comment: @Amjad Looks like reassigning is (albeit negligently) slower.

Comment: @alex: FWIW, in Firefox 6, reassigning is (negligibly) faster.

Comment: @Felix I got the opposite on my Firefox 6 on Windows XP.

Comment: @alex: I run it on OS X 10.7. But after running it a couple of times, there is no definite answer. One time reassigning is (slightly slighty) faster, one time the other way. This is really does not seem to go anywhere (at least in Firefox ;)).

Comment: @Felix when the difference is that small they're practically equal in performance, try running it again, you may get the opposite of what you got just the time before, at least that whats happening on chrome.

Comment: @Amjad: Don't know if you read my last comment, but yes, that is exactly what I experienced (and that's what I meant). So, the whole thing is nothing really to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> function Abc(a, b, c) {
>     var window = window;
```

> So when the code accesses window, it doesn't need to go up the scope
>   chain to finally find window.

I don't think that's the reason. For a function declared in global scope, resolving an identifier locally versus globally will be insignificanly faster (and perhaps slower depending on the browser).

Scripts may use something similar to the above to ensure *window* refers to the expected *window* object and not some other *window* on the scope chain, e.g.

```
var fn = (function(window) {

  // In here window is unequivocally a reference to the global object

}(this));
```

In the second example:

```
> function Scroller(elm, dw, settings) {
>     ...
>     var elm = elm;
>     var dw = dw;
>     ...
```

Declaring the variables is complete waste of time. Putting an identifier in the formal parameter list of a function declaration or expression is equivalent to declaring it localling with *var*. Declaring such identifiers as local variables has no effect whatever.

There was an early version of Safari that had an issue with formal parameters that weren't passed a value, but that was a long time ago and was only an issue in one very specific case.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the answer: Yes, for global functions, there will be no big difference. But often functions are nested in other functions, used as callbacks etc. and there it makes sense to get any object as close as possible. It also depends on *how often* a certain object is accessed. A rule of thumb is, if you access a property or object more than once, store it in a local variable.

Comment: @Felix King I don't use that rule of thumb at all -- my rule of thumb is "...if it makes the code more readable/maintainable then..." which has *nothing* to do with "performance" or "count".

Comment: @pst: Of course readability is above all. Unless you really need high performance code, and actually I had this in mind. *[High Performance JavaScript](http://www.amazon.com/Performance-JavaScript-Faster-Application-Interfaces/dp/059680279X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1314152171&sr=8-1)* is a nice book to read in this regard. Of course if you have no performance problem then you don't have to optimize for performance.

Comment: @Felix - keeping object property access short is useful, but my usual motivation is less typing. :-) For identifiers resolved on the scope chain, I think the performance difference is insignificant, there are other things to focus on (readability is one). If scope chains are so long that they are creating performance issues, likely there are bigger design issues to address or at least review.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical reason is potentially clarifying what scope the variable was declared in.

Other then that it just adds excess code.