# Javascript Object initialization

Tags: javascript

I am trying to initialize a Javascript object like.

```
function showKabineninfo(W3CElement) {
  params = params || {};
  ...
  ...       
}
```

But I am getting Javascript error that "params is undefined"

Comment: are you trying to use `params` from some where else?

Comment: hmm, what object are you initializing? What is W3CElement? What is params? It is very hard to correctly answer a question without knowing what you *actually* want to do.

Answer (score 1):

its because the `params` variable is only defined in the scope of the function

try this:

```
function showKabineninfo(W3CElement) {
  window.params = window.params || {};
  ...
  ...       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't defined **`params`** in the argument list, you should change the code, adding **var** and as pointed by missingno it is better to use another variable to hold the value of params:

```
function showKabineninfo(W3CElement) {
  // reassigning - bad practice!
  //var params = params || {};
  var aParams = params || {};
  ...       
}
```

in the case when **`params`** is present. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495174/javascript-do-i-need-to-use-var-when-reassigning-a-variable-defined-in-the-f)

In addition I think usage of:

```
window.params = window.params || {};
```

is even worst because of the usage of global variables, which in programming is not considered good practice.

Comment: I mean, just prefixing the "var" will probably not be very useful since params is being used on the right-hand-side of the assignment as well. Anyway, its hard to guess the *correct* solution since the original question is so vague.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var params = params || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

By `params = params || {};`, do you mean that you wish to refer to the array of parameters that are passed?
If so, try `arguments`, `arguments[0]` should be `W3CElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance mean this?

```
function showKabineninfo(W3CElement, params) {
   var params = params || {};
}
```